# macos 10.10 import MySQLdb error

Tags: python

import MySQLdb error message

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in 
> > >           import _mysql
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
> > >         Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so
> > >         Reason: image not found

Comment: Have you tried this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to this lines:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Have you mysql client installed on system?

Also you can try:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some [documentation](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) on importing MySQL and using it with Python. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import _mysql
import sys

try:
    con = _mysql.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb')

    con.query("SELECT VERSION()")
    result = con.use_result()

    print "MySQL version: %s" % \
        result.fetch_row()[0]

except _mysql.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```